# the style does not work on images (Image) how can I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

the style does not work on images (Image); how can I fix it?
For example, style 2-card is applied without an image
but when I add images, the style changes, I don't understand why.
Icons are visible on Card-2, but after adding an image on card-1, the photo closes the icons

```
export default class Cards extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            
            <View style={{...styles.container, backgroundColor:this.props.bg }}>
                <View style={styles.col}>

                    <Image 
                        style={styles.col}
                        source={this.props.imageUri}
                    />
                    <Icon 
                        name={this.props.icon}
                        size={30}
                        color={this.props.bg == "red" ? "red":"red"}
                    />
                       
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress}>
                        <Icon2
                            style={{marginLeft:50}}
                            name="dots-vertical"
                            size={30}
                            color="red"
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                   
                </View>
            
                <Text style={styles.title}>{this.props.title}</Text>
                <Text style={{
                    ...styles.number,
                    color: this.props.bg == "red" ? "#FFF":"#000",
                }}>
                    {this.props.number}
                </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
    
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    height:200,
    width:130,
    borderRadius:30,
    padding:15,
    marginLeft:20
  },
  
  col: {
    flexDirection:"row"
  },
  
  title:{
    marginTop:90,
    color:"#b8b8aa",
    fontWeight:"bold",
    fontSize:12
  },

  number:{
    fontWeight:'bold',
    fontSize:22
  }
})
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80lHT.jpg)

Comment: That might caused by by resizeMode. 
Can you share your style definitions?

Comment: @MichaelBahl added style and updated the code, thanks for the help)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/rounded-rect-images) based on your code.

Basically `overflow: 'hidden'` of the container did the trick